# How to scroll to element cross browser using jquery animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, scroll, jquery-animate

This code:

```
jQuery('body').animate({scrollTop: target.offset().top}, 300);
```

Works in firefox, but not chrome.

This code:

```
jQuery('html').animate({scrollTop: target.offset().top}, 300);
```

Works in chrome, but not firefox.

I haven't tested yet in IE.

What is the correct way to do this, cross-browser? If it's not clear from the above snippets, I target is a div on the page, and I want to scroll down slowly to it slowly, so they do exactly what I want... just not cross-browser.

Comment: I seem to recall having to amend the selector to include both `html` and `body`, i.e.:  `"html,body"`.

Comment: I had a similar problem with my jQuery fadein on my site.

Answer (score 4):

Specify both `html` and `body`:

```
$("html,body").animate({scrollTop: target.offset().top}, 300);
```

Comment: And for internet explorer?

Comment: It did when I tried it, just wondered which (html/body) ie used, or whether there was some other function that was more recommended for use with ie.

Comment: Note that if you supply a callback for the `.animate()`, it could be executed twice (once for each element, `html` and `body`).  This can be solved with moving the callback from the `.animate()` to `.promise().done(myCallback)`